# Need to find out date when account become

Tags: sql, t-sql

If summ is positive `+` that means account own money, if record has  negative `-` that means account has a payment.
I need to find out which account don't own any money on today date and I have this query :

```
SELECT  a.Customer
       ,a.Deal
       ,(a.positive + b.negative) AS own_to_the_bank
FROM    (
          SELECT    SUM(Summ) AS positive
                   ,Customer
                   ,Deal
          FROM      #test
          WHERE     Summ > 0
          GROUP BY  Customer
                   ,Deal
        ) AS a 
JOIN    (
          SELECT    SUM(Summ) AS negative
                   ,Customer
                   ,Deal
          FROM      #test
          WHERE     Summ < 0
          GROUP BY  Customer
                   ,Deal
        ) AS b ON a.Customer = b.Customer
                  AND a.Deal = b.Deal
WHERE a.positive + b.negative >0
```

and its working fine so now I have to find-out when account stops owning any money to the bank when `a.positive + b.negative = 0` from my query.
stuck with this problem for few hours, any help?

Answer (score 1):

I started with creating the balance per day, customer, deal and currency

```
SELECT t1.Customer, t1.Deal, t1.Currency, t1.Date, Balance = (SELECT SUM(Summ) FROM #test as hist WHERE hist.Customer = t1.Customer and hist.Deal = t1.Deal and hist.Currency = t1.Currency and hist.Date <= t1.Date)
FROM #test as t1
```

Added condition for positive balance and a rownum (ordered by date)

```
SELECT Customer, Deal, Currency, Date, Balance, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, Deal, Currency ORDER BY Date) 
FROM
(
            select t1.Customer, t1.Deal, t1.Currency, t1.Date, Balance = (SELECT SUM(Summ) FROM #test as hist WHERE hist.Customer = t1.Customer and hist.Deal = t1.Deal and hist.Currency = t1.Currency and hist.Date <= t1.Date)
            FROM #test as t1
             ) as inn
WHERE Balance > 0
```

At last picked the first one.

```
SELECT Customer, Deal, Currency, Date, Balance
FROM (  SELECT Customer, Deal, Currency, Date, Balance, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, Deal, Currency ORDER BY Date) 
        FROM
        (
                    SELECT t1.Customer, t1.Deal, t1.Currency, t1.Date, Balance = (SELECT SUM(Summ) FROM #test as hist WHERE hist.Customer = t1.Customer and hist.Deal = t1.Deal and hist.Currency = t1.Currency and hist.Date <= t1.Date)
                    FROM #test as t1
                     ) as t
        WHERE Balance > 0 ) as t2
WHERE t2.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You may have several dates for a customer when he stopped owing

for example here we have two dates:

```
+1000
+500
-500
+500
-500
```

This query shows the last one:

```
select distinct a.customer, a.date
from test as a 
left join test as b 
on a.Date > b.Date and a.Customer = b.Customer 
where a.summ < 0 and b.summ > 0 
group by a.customer order by a.date, b.date desc
```

The clue is ordering joined tables in different directions by date and then taking just the first line per customer.

Comment: yes the problem that I need to show only  the last  date  since customer start  owning the money. also your query  throws 2 errors

Comment: @Andrey i have no errors in mysql 5.5.43. Mysql is the most used database (i think), so if you use some other DB, you must specify that in your question. Also, show me your errors, please?

Comment: sorry  I am using MS SQL i think i specify it in tags as tsql